# Provisional profile is missing when building for iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I am able to create the .ipa file for 4.2, but it fails when I do it for 5.0. In 5.0 when I archive the build, the provisioning profile is missing.

It successfully runs in the simulator and in my iPhone. When I select "Product->Archive" to build the archive, it successfully archives the project but it losses the identifier name, and the version is 'Unspecified'. When I press the "Share" button it doesn't find the provisioning profile and can't build the ipa file.

How can I get the ipa file built?

Answer (score 1):

you need to download the .mobileprovision files from developer.apple.com. You can just double click the files in finder and install them. Be sure in the build settings to point them to proper distro profiles/developer profiles.

Comment: Umm i have done that. With the same profile i am being able to .ipa for other projects. But in this project it is not working :( I can create .ipa for 4.2... but when i try to do that for 5.0 it says provisioning profile is missing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - Actually the the project was done with xcode 3.2.6 and it had two dependencies. When it was transitioned to 4.2, build setting wasn't changed. I had to convert the build settings of 2 dependencies and the main application then i could build the ipa file.